# Clarifying my beer

Tags: beer, clarification, cloudy

I would like to know, the easiest way to clarify my beer. To avoid chill Haze if there's a way to avoid that. Any and all help be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I noticed when I put my beer in the refrigerator too cold carbonate I get a haze. Not that bad, but I would like to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same trials and tribulations that you're experiencing. I have made wine for years and used Super-Klear as a fining agent, which always worked wonders in clarifying my wines. In beer, I had mixed results.
So, reading online, I decided to try plain unflavored gelatin, mixing about 1 tsp of gelatin into 1 cup water at 150F.  I usually boil the water first to sanitize it, then allow it to cool to 150F, add the gelatin, stir to dissolve and then add, stirring into the beer. Being able to place the beer in a refrigerator will definitely help the process along. Usually in 2-3 days you can see results. It is my go to process now, my beer is crystal clear.
There are other brewing processes that will benefit the clearing process, a vigorous boil, followed by a quick cooling process helps. Additionally using Whirfloc in the last 10 minutes of the boil, has shown to benefit clearing.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed many times, take a look at:

- [What is chill haze and how to get rid of it](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11367/what-is-chill-haze-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-chill-haze)
- [How to clear beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9482/how-to-clear-beer?rq=1)
- [How to get clearer home brewed beers](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/how-to-get-clearer-and-more-clarified-home-brewed-beers?rq=1)
- [What causes cloudiness in beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/what-causes-cloudiness-in-beer?rq=1)

To sum up the answers, I can recommend :

1. Leaving beer more time in secondary
2. Store at colder temperature for a longer time
3. Use finings agents
4. Filter the beer

If possible, leave your beer in a secondary (glass carboy) for a few additional weeks at a colder temperature.  If longer time is not an option, the use of a fining agent will do the job, but I find that it also strips some flavor and color. Filtering is also an option, but it may also filter the remaining yeast in suspension, so this is not suitable for bottle conditionning.